# How to get control panel settings value like font size

Tags: c++, dpi

```
    int CMonitor::GetDPI() const
{
    HDC hdc = CreateDC();
    int dpiX = ::GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX);
    int dpiY = ::GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY);
    ReleaseDC(hdc));
    return dpiY > dpiX ? dpiY : dpiX;
}
```

In my application DPIAware tag is false and that's why it give me 96 all the time, whether my font size is 150% or 200%

I want actual DPI value like for 150%. It should give me 144, rather than 96.

There is one API which is `GetDpiForWindow`, give me that but it is not compatible with Windows 7.

I want any API which is compatible with Windows 7 and give me actual DPI.

Comment: Google "c++ dpiaware manifest" for basic hits.

Comment: Maybe the easiest way is for your app to be dpi aware?

Comment: @davidbak i know, but i want the solution in dpi aware false

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
int desktopWidth = GetDeviceCaps(screen, DESKTOPHORZRES); 
int displayWidth = GetDeviceCaps(screen, HORZRES);
```

Here first one gives actual width as of DPI True effect and second gives DPI false width, so by dividing them i got actual DPI and font size.

DESKTOPHORZRES is not given on MSDN